# Fastest way to get sort order byte array from signed integer

Tags: c#, signed, bitconverter

I know I can use bitconverter.GetBytes to get the bytes from an integer.
However, I need an array where the contents can be compared for sort order.

e.g.

```
var plusOne = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
yields bytes: 0,0,0,1

var plusOne = BitConverter.GetBytes(2);
yields bytes: 0,0,0,2
```

So far so good:

but:

```
var minusOne = BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
yields bytes: 255,255,255,255
```

Nothing strange here.
But comparing the minusOne byte array with the plusOne bytearray would say that the minusOne byte array is greater than the plusOne (255 > 0)

Is there any fancy way to shift, xor etc, so that Int.Min would give 0,0,0,0 and int.Max would give 255,255,255,255  ??

Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `int.MaxValue + 1` to the current value casted to an uint to preserve the range like:

```
var result = BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)((long)input - int.MinValue));
```

Comment: I came up with this solution ´unchecked((uint)(int.MinValue ^ (1 << 31)))   doesnt need to fall over into a bigger datatype there..